# jQuery how to use .find

Tags: jquery

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr id="myRow1">
        <td>hi</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>comeon</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

1. In the above scenario, what's the difference between

   `$("#myTable").find('tr')`

   and

   `$("#myTable").find('tr')[0]` or `$("#myTable").find('tr').get(0)`?
2. Also given `$("#myTable").find('tr')[0]`, how do I get the number of `td`s under it?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't understand why **$("#myTable").find('tr')[0].find('td')** doesn't work, but **$("#myTable").find('tr').find('td')** works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `[i]` or `.get(i)` syntax unless you really have to, those are ways of accessing the underlying elements within the jQuery object.

The jQuery object is designed to be a wrapper around the elements.

`.find()` is a jQuery function, it only works on jQuery objects.  If you extract the underlying element, it is no longer a jQuery object, just a regular element, so you can not use `.find()` on it.

If you need the first element only, then use the jQuery filter to get that, leaving the result as a jQuery object.  Also, you only really need to use `.find()` if you are using the part before separately first.

These are the same:

```
$('#myTable').find('tr:first').find('td');
$('#myTable tr:first td');
```

Comment: Which one is more efficient?

Comment: @isurfbecause: Between using `.find()` and the all-in-one selector? Probably the latter, the answer says as much.  If you mean between direct access and using the selector, then probably direct access is quicker, but does not give you a jQuery object to work with, which means a further wrap around, which likely nullifies the speed gain.

Answer (score 2):

Comeonman, if you want `$("#myTable").find('tr')[0].find('td')`  to work, use this:

```
$($("#myTable").find('tr')[0]).find('td') // should work
```

`$(an_obj)` will convert the `an_obj` into a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myTable").find('tr')
```

will query all `tr` elements in the table `#myTable` and returns them in a **jQuery wrapped set**.

```
$("#myTable").find('tr')[0]
```

will query all `tr` elements in the same table, but returns the first **DOM element** (not the jQuery object)

```
$("#myTable").find('tr').get(0)
```

the exact same as above.

As I mentioned above, `$("#myTable").find('tr')[0]` returns a `DOM element`. You would need native Javascript & DOM functions to grab all `<td>` nodes. Doing it with jQuery would look like

```
$("#myTable").find('td').length
```

will return the number of `<td>` nodes in the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

> Also given `$("#myTable").find('tr')[0]`, how do I get the number of 'td' s under it?

Since you're referencing a DOM element, [use the native `cells` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement).

```
var len = $("#myTable").find('tr')[0].cells.length;
```

Comment: Simpler to do `$('#myTable tr:first td').size()`

Comment: @Orbling: I tend to avoid using selectors like `:first` since they're much less efficient in many browsers. If I was to simplify it and make it more efficient at the same time, I'd do it like this: `$("#myTable")[0].rows[0].cells[0].length`. This way it's targeting a specific row right from the start instead of filtering it down to the `:first`.

Comment: If efficiency is the goal, then yes.  I tend to like to keep the jQuery/sizzle paradigm as clean as possible instead.

Comment: My code in the comment above should have been `.rows[0].cells.length` without the `[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery selectors, you're getting back a wrapped set of DOM elements, not just a simple array.  When you use [0] to select a single element, you lose the wrapper and can no longer use jQuery methods on that element.  If you want to retrieve the first row in a table, you can do so by using the :first selector.

```
$("#mytable").find('tr:first')
```

This will provide you with a wrapped set consisting of just the first tr element in your table.  To get the number of td elements in that tr, you can use the size() method.

```
$("#mytable").find('tr:first').find('td').size()
```

I don't have time to test this right now, but it looks right.  If it doesn't work for you, please let me know and I'll update as needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. The difference is that in the first selector you're actually selecting all `<tr>` elements in `#myTable`, and in the second and third, you're just selecting the first index in that that same array, which will always be one `<tr>` element (although it may have an arbitrary `n` children)
2. `$("#myTable").find('tr').eq(0).children('td').length`

Note that in #2 ... you're only going to select the `<td>` children of the *first* `<tr>` element that are in the `$("#myTable").find('tr')` selector.  The easiest way of selecting all of the `<td>` elements in a table is: `$("#myTable").find('td')` ... if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: this will not work since [0] gets the underlaying `DOM node` which doesn't know about a method like `.children()`